# Getting code to cycle through multiple inputs for a test

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am trying to make a multiple choice test for an RPG website. 
Their are 14 questions, and each one has 8 answers.

Each of the 8 answers corresponds to an object with 8 properties. 
The answers ( given that I get the code to recognize each individual type) 
will add + 1 to each property, at the end of the test a comparison will run between the values of the properties and spit out the proper result.

Current Problem:

I have pieced together  this code: (the full code will be below)

```
// Go through all questions and add +1 for each checked
// input with a value = "monk" 

$('#test').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($('input[name = answer]:checked').val() == "monk"){
            secondaryResults.mnk++;
        console.log(secondaryResults);
        }


    })
```

Now the above works perfectly and exactly how I want it to work, it goes through all 14 questions adding up the answers that are tagged " monk" adding it to the property of the object secondaryResults.

However if you add in similar code to do the same thing for answers tagged " berserker" it ends up adding berserker to monk, giving skewed results.

For example:

Question 1 : Answer = monk

Question 2 : Answer = monk

question 3:  Answer = Berserker

question 4:  Answer = Thief

with this code I expected the console.log to spit out

Monk:2

Berserker: 1

Thief:1

instead it spits out monk:4

I've tried creating the same function just for a different variable (below you'll see the second attempt for the value/var berserker/ber) and attaching it to the same click event. I also tried putting it inside the .each() function as well as inside the first .on() function. I get the same results each time

So **question**: what would I need to include in the above section of code, to make the code:

1. Continue to count each individual occurence of a chec,k for all 8 properties
2. Store the users score inside the object (shown below) for later use.

currently the code does this, but only for one input value/variable which is Monk- shortened to mnk in the object.

All Script:

```
$(window).load(function() { 

$(".intro").appendTo('#display_box');
var question = $(".question");
var questionPosition = -1;

var secondaryResults = {
    def:0,
    ber:0,
    mnk:0,
    rng:0,
    cle:0,
    thf:0,
    mge:0,
};

var primaryResults = {
    def:0,
    ber:0,
    mnk:0,
    rng:0,
    cle:0,
    thf:0,
    mge:0,
};



function clearBox(){
    $("#display_box").children().fadeOut(500).appendTo('#question_holding');
};



function cycle(){

    question.eq(questionPosition).fadeIn(500).appendTo("#display_box");
    $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0}, 500);


}





    $('#leftarrow').on('click', function(){
    questionPosition--;
    if (questionPosition <= -1) {questionPosition = 13};
    clearBox();
    cycle();





});





$('#rightarrow').on('click', function(){
    questionPosition++;
    if (questionPosition > 13) { questionPosition = 0};
    clearBox();
    cycle();

    if($('input[name^="answer"]:checked').length > 13 ) {
        $("#submit").css('display', 'block');
    }




});
$('#test').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($('input[name = answer]:checked').val() == "monk"){
            secondaryResults.mnk++;
        console.log(secondaryResults);
        }


    })



});

$('#test').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($('input[name = answer]:checked').val() == "berserker"){
            secondaryResults.ber++;
        console.log(secondaryResults);
        }


    })


});

});
```

Comment: could you add some html?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to reference the current element within your each loop.

```
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($('input[name = answer]:checked').val() == "monk"){
            secondaryResults.mnk++;
        console.log(secondaryResults);
        }
    })
```

change to something like:

```
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monk"){
            secondaryResults.mnk++;
        console.log(secondaryResults);
        }
    })
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/misc_each.asp